# How can I remove the residue that is building up in PEX tubing?

Tags: cleaning, water-pressure, pex

I have a pex plumbing system that has been slowly clogging / losing pressure.  Our sulphur treatment system injects peroxide into the pressure tank then flows upstairs to the filter system.  The oxidizing process creates a white film (from the chemical reaction).  And this seems to be getting thicker over the years.  Anyways I believe this is the source of the problem.  I am curious if there is an easy way to clean the inside of the pex tubing out between the pressure tank and filter?  Was thinking of running vinegar through the chemical feeder line - and letting it dissolve in the lines.  Not sure if that is a good idea or not.  Any thoughts?

Comment: What system do you have in your home that uses peroxide in a pressure tank? Is this a heating system?

Answer (score 2):

Nobody knows how to clean PEX tubing, because it's a plastic pipe. On your side I will think about repiping all your the clogged lines. PEX tubing prices have become close to nothing.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure of the best way, but you may able to blow some of the material out of your system using an air compressor.

I got the idea from watching a house get winterized. The plumber shut off all of the water to the house and opened up every single tap and let all the water come out. He also attached a hose to the hot water tank and drained that out.

After all the lines were drained, he closed all the taps and attached an air compressor to the system and charged it up to 80 psi or so. Then he opened the taps one by one and then closed them to let the pressure build back up. He went around the house multiple times doing this until only air came out of the pipes.

If you did the same thing, it may release any clogs or debris trapped in your lines. Once you are done, you should also remove all of the aerators from your faucets and clean out any debris that is clogging them up.

This may not completely fix the problem, but it beats having to rip everything apart and redo it.